# Google+ Android grid widget for tablet tutorial

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, google-plus, pinterest

I would like to build an heterogeneous grid widget in Android like the one is used in apps like Google+ for tablets or Pinterest. I cannot find any tutorial and it seems particularly difficult.

[image]

Unfortunately `GridView` can have only cells of same size while I want to achieve different sizes cells. Can you point me to any good tutorial? I only know that I have to extend `AbsListView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how variable the items' heights are, you have a few options:

1. If you're looking to do a `GridView` with many variations of heights (e.g. Pinterest) you should play around with [StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)  - as far as I can tell, it's the best open source solution out there right now.
2. In the image you posted, it looks as if there are parent rows with variable height children - this is a slightly easier problem to solve, and can be mimicked by using a regular ol' `ListView` and a subclass of `BaseAdapter`. Writing out the code for this is too involved for a SO answer, but i'll give you an overview of how I might achieve this effect.

   - The `BaseAdapter` must determine the rough layout of each row ahead of time such that it can report to the listview how many rows it will require - you'll need to override `getCount()`.
   - In `getView()` of your adapter, you will inflate a single `LinearLayout` (or perhaps use convertView if it's been recycled) and add as many children (again, more `LinearLayouts`) as you will require for the width of the device (you should figure this out at runtime, unless you want to just create a phone and tablet version).
   - Each child `LinearLayout` added to the row should be set to weight=1 such that they stretch to the entire width of the parent row. In the screenshot you posted, there are 3 columns (the third id cut off).
   - Each child `LinearLayout` you just added to the row represents a column. You should set their orientations to vertical, being as they are columns!
   - Within each column, if you were to add a single child, you'd have a gridview.
   - If you wish to achieve the effect above, you can add more items to each column.
   - For example, row 1, column 1 has one large child. Columns 2 and 3 in row 1 both have 2 half-height children.